# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(...) at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I've looked at many other posts about this same problem, but I still can't seem to find out what is wrong with my code.  Mind you, I started learning PHP and SQL this week, so please excuse me if I made a stupid mistake.  Also, I'm sure it's worth noting that before the error message that is posted in the title appeared, there was another error (defined in my code).  That error was:

> " already exists."

That tells me that the `$_POST["file"]["name"]` variable is not set for whatever reason.  Any help is appreciated.  However, if you are going to tell me that my code is vulnerable to SQL injection, I know that.  The upload script is only accessible through my (secure) login script.  Again, all help is welcome!

```php
<?php
  /* Process uploaded file */

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
      if (file_exists($_POST["class"] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists.";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        $_POST["class"] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newpath = mysql_real_escape_string("uploads/" . $_POST['class'] . "/" . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['file']['name']);
        $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . $newpath;
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "File must be less than two megabytes.";
  }

  /* Create and store information in MySQL Database */

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("1169030_dsp", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO $_POST[class] (Description, Filename, File)
VALUES
  ('$description','$filename','$newpath')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Your file was successfully uploaded.";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

Here is my input form HTML:

```
  <center>
    <form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" style="background-color:#009933;color:#FFFFFF;width:320px;text-align:left;">
  Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>
  File:        <input type="file" name="file"><br>
      Class:<br>
  <Select name="Class">
    <option value="period1">APES : period1</option>
    <option value="period2">Chemistry I : period2</option>
    <option value="period3">Lab Assist/Sci : period 3</option>
    <option value="period4">Lab Assist/Sci : period 4</option>
    <option value="period4">APES : period 4</option>
    <option value="period5">APES : period 5</option>
    <option value="period6">Lab Assist/Sci : period 6</option>
    <option value="period7">Chemistry I : period 7</option>
  </Select><br>
      <input type="submit" name="Upload">
</form>
  <center>
```

Comment: If you've just recently started PHP, then you should avoid the `mysql_*` functions entirely.  They're due to be removed, so you should investigate one of the [alternative MySQL libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead...

Comment: print  $sql in the error. it will help you debug.

Comment: For future reference, remove database login credentials from your code before posting it on the Internet. I had to do some voodoo here to get them removed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  To help debug this problem, I recommend you echo out the contents of $sql, prior to executing the statement. That will help identify the problem.

Comment: What should the value of $_POST[class] be? You have at least a / in the value, so is it a real table name?

Comment: And while it's good that you are aware of the risk of SQL injection, it's better to scrape this kind of code and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Because they automatically handle your input, they don't just protect you from SQL injection, but also from malformed input. For example, if your `$description` contains a single-quote (`'`), it will break your query. Prepared statements solve that.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it  Oli.  I'll try the $sql debug method as well Byron and Spencer.  Wow, I didn't even notice, thank you NullUserException.  Mark, $_POST[class] is the result of a dropbox in my upload.html.  The code is as follows for the entire input form:

Comment: `<form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" style="background-color:#009933;color:#FFFFFF;width:320px;text-align:left;">
  Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>
  File:        <input type="file" name="file"><br>
      Class:<br>
  <Select name="Class">
    <option value="period1">APES : period1</option>
    <option value="period2">Chemistry I : period2</option>
    <option value="period3">Lab Assist/Sci : period 3</option>
    <option value="period4">Lab Assist/Sci : period 4</option>
    <option value="period4">APES : period 4</option>`

Comment: What happens if you change the `$_POST[class]` var to a hardcoded value (i.e. one of the class values)?

Comment: `<option value="period5">APES : period 5</option>
    <option value="period6">Lab Assist/Sci : period 6</option>
    <option value="period7">Chemistry I : period 7</option>
  </Select><br>
      <input type="submit" name="Upload">
</form>`

Comment: Put the html in the question, it's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I replaced all of the variables that I was inserting into my table with `$_POST[description]` and it successfully returned the string that was entered into the form for that variable.  However, the error still occurred except it said `already exists.Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Description, Filename, File) VALUES ('description','description','description')' at line 1`  This tells me that the error is elsewhere in the script.

Comment: That sounds like an indexing issue. Check your table schema to make sure you're not trying to insert something into a unique column that isn't unique.

Comment: Thanks again to everybody who helped!  Also, I will look into prepared statements NullUserException.  It's amazing how quickly everybody could respond to my question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your form does not have the enctype attribute set. It should be:

```
<form action="uploadfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="background-color:#009933;color:#FFFFFF;width:320px;text-align:left;">
```

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required for `$_FILES` to be populated.

Comment: That worked!  you fixed the error I was getting, but now I'm being thrown 8 new errors.  I will look into them and try to solve them.  I'll be back if I need more help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your variable `$_POST[class]` is wrong , it should be `$_POST['class']`

try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $_POST['class'] (Description, Filename, File)
       VALUES
      ('".$description."','".$filename."','".$newpath."')";
```

Comment: now I get this error when I try that goodmood:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /srv/disk11/1169030/www/thelandofscience.co.nf/uploadfile.php on line 41`

Comment: $_POST[class] will assume constant value of class but it will likely just throw an error and accept it as $_POST['class'] anyhow. The bigger issue here is you're just tossing a post variable into your query with no sanitizing. FYI though, it is generally good form to quote array keys to avoid errors.